# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Warnings when running using npm run test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

I am a newbie to `MongoDB` and I am using `mongoose` library to help me store data in MongoDB. Though all my (`mocha`) test pass, I still  keep getting this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
  at C:\MY STUFF\CODING\Projects\mongodb tutorial\mongodb-playlist\test\finding_test.js:33:21
  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
  This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, 
  or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()
  DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. 
  In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate 
  the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my code:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const MarioChar = require('../models/mariochar');


describe('Finding records', function(){
  // this.timeout(15000);
  var char;

  beforeEach(function(done){
    char = new MarioChar({
      name: 'Mario'
    });

    // now test it
    char.save().then(function(){
      // done(); 
    });
    done();
  });

  it('Finds one record from the database', function(done){
    // this.timeout(15000);
    MarioChar.findOne({name: 'Mario'}).then(function(result){
      assert(result.name === 'Mario');
      // done();
    });
    done();
  });

  it('Finds one record by ID from the database', function(done){

    MarioChar.findOne({_id: char._id}).then(function(result){
      assert(result._id.toString() === char._id.toString());
      // done();
    });
    done();
  });
});
```

The comments are what all I tried in order to remove those errors/warnings.

When I run using `mocha --trace-warnings finding_test.js` I get no warnings, however if I run using this command  `npm run test`, I get these warnings.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your error says `Cannot read property 'name' of null`.

That means you are trying to access property called `name` on a variable that should point to an object but is actually `null`.

The only place in your code where you are accessing `name` is:

```
MarioChar.findOne({name: 'Mario'}).then(function(result){
  assert(result.name === 'Mario'); // <---- here
});
```

This means that, at the point this code runs, there is no document with `name: 'Mario'` in your db.

The reason this is happening is because in your `beforeEach` hook you are not waiting for the document to be created.

You are calling `done` before creation:

```
beforeEach(function(done){
  char = new MarioChar({
    name: 'Mario'
  });

  char.save().then(function(){
    // this part is called when the document is created
  });
  done(); // this executes before document is created
});
```

You should call it after saving (and also on error):

```
beforeEach(function(done){
  char = new MarioChar({
    name: 'Mario'
  });

  char.save()
   .then(done)   // we are done when successful
   .catch(done); // and when erroring
});
```

You should also be able to use an async function for better readability:

```
beforeEach(async function() {
  char = await new MarioChar({
    name: 'Mario'
  }).save();
});
```

Note: You have a few other places where you aren't calling `done` properly, like in your tests (the `it` calls). You have to call `done` within those callbacks as well or return the promises.

For example, this:

```
it('Finds one record from the database', function(done){
  MarioChar.findOne({name: 'Mario'}).then(function(result){
    assert(result.name === 'Mario');
  });
  done();
});
```

Should either be:

```
it('Finds one record from the database', function(done){
  MarioChar.findOne({name: 'Mario'}).then(function(result){
    assert(result.name === 'Mario');
    done(); // call done here
  })
  .catch(done); // and here
});
```

Or (return a promise):

```
it('Finds one record from the database', function(){
  return MarioChar.findOne({name: 'Mario'}).then(function(result){
    assert(result.name === 'Mario');
  });
});
```

Or (using an async function):

```
it('Finds one record from the database', async function(){
  const result = await MarioChar.findOne({name: 'Mario'});
   assert(result.name === 'Mario');
});
```

Comment: *Should either be* - it shouldn't. Mocha naturally supports promises, using done results in boilerplate code which is prone to human mistakes, I see this one all the time. This one will result in test timeout and unhandled rejection, `done` is never called when the assertion fails. A proper way to do this with done is `MarioChar.findOne(...).then(...).then(done, done)`

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I was able to fix this ```finding_test.js```. However, I have other code ```updating_test.js```. It is similar to the above code, just that for the ```it``` block I get this error ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: The expression evaluated to a falsy value: assert(result.name === 'Luigi')``` for ```MarioChar.findOneAndUpdate({name: 'Mario'}, {name: 'Luigi'}).then(function(){ MarioChar.findOne({_id:char._id}).then(function(result){       assert(result.name === 'Luigi'); done(); }); });```    Help plz!

Comment: @estus you are correct. I was mainly going for the happy path solution but I edited accordingly to handle errors. Thanks for the comment.